# Twilio call phone number masking using C# API

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I need to connect two customer via voice call, but I want to hide original phone number from each other. I'm planning to implement it using twilio. My current progress is up to making a call from twilio.

```
const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            const string authToken = "fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx";
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var to = new PhoneNumber("+91XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            var from = new PhoneNumber("+1XXXXXXXX");
            var call = CallResource.Create(to, from,
                url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
```

Now I am not getting the part where I need to mask phone number, and adding two party's to have a voice conversation via twilio.

I am confused how to start, I've gone through https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/masked-numbers-csharp-mvc , but not able to understand it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so you've made a call and you got the demo response when you answer the call. The next stage is to provide your own URL when you make a call and tell Twilio what to do by returning [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml). I would look into [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and for number masking check out the [`callerId` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid). What was hard to understand with the tutorial? Did you try to run the code and see what happened?

Comment: @philnash Thanks for your help, but implemented this with twilio proxy. its much easier to implement.

Comment: Ah, glad that Proxy was the right choice here. I can't believe I didn't think to suggest it!

Comment: @philnash no Problem, thanks for you help.